# cancel UIAlertView programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uialertview, alert

How can I cancel a `UIAlertView` programmatically?
This is the code that I use to show the UIAlertView

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save Background" message:@"Downloading..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 70.0);
    [myAlertView setTransform:myTransform];
    [myAlertView show];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:` like this:

Here is the code to use:

```
[myAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
```

Comment: +1 to you for being 20 seconds faster than while I was typing it in... ["`cancelButtonIndex`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIAlertView/cancelButtonIndex) isn't always going to be "`-1`", though.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it via

```
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated
```

while calling the "cancel" button index.

You could also simply remove the alert view from the superview (i.e. "`removeFromSuperview`").  Make sure to "`release`" the alloc'd view in case you are not using ARC.